# Checking if ElementTree node is empty failure

Tags: python, elementtree

I keep getting the error: `AttributeError: 'NodeList' object has no attribute 'data'`, but I am just trying to check if that node is empty, and if so, just pass a -1 instead of the value. My understanding is `temp_pub.getElementsByTagName("pages").data` should return `None`. How do I fix this?

(p.s.- I've tried `!= None` and `is None`)

```
xmldoc = minidom.parse('pubsClean.xml')

#loop through <pub> tags to find number of pubs to grab
root = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName("root")[0]
pubs = [a.firstChild.data for a in root.getElementsByTagName("pub")]
num_pubs = len(pubs)
count = 0

while(count < num_pubs):

    temp_pages = 0
    #get data from each <pub> tag
    temp_pub = root.getElementsByTagName("pub")[count]
    temp_ID = temp_pub.getElementsByTagName("ID")[0].firstChild.data
    temp_title = temp_pub.getElementsByTagName("title")[0].firstChild.data
    temp_year = temp_pub.getElementsByTagName("year")[0].firstChild.data
    temp_booktitle = temp_pub.getElementsByTagName("booktitle")[0].firstChild.data
    #handling no value
    if temp_pub.getElementsByTagName("pages").data != None:  
        temp_pages = temp_pub.getElementsByTagName("pages")[0].firstChild.data
    else: 
        temp_pages = -1

    temp_authors = temp_pub.getElementsByTagName("authors")[0]
    temp_author_array = [a.firstChild.data for a in temp_authors.getElementsByTagName("author")]
    num_authors = len(temp_author_array)
    count = count + 1
```

**XML being processed**

```
<pub>
    <ID>5010</ID>
    <title>Model-Checking for L<sub>2</sub</title>
    <year>1997</year>
    <booktitle>Universit&auml;t Trier, Mathematik/Informatik, Forschungsbericht</booktitle>
    <pages></pages>
    <authors>
        <author>Helmut Seidl</author>
    </authors>
</pub>
<pub>
    <ID>5011</ID>
    <title>Locating Matches of Tree Patterns in Forest</title>
    <year>1998</year>
    <booktitle>Universit&auml;t Trier, Mathematik/Informatik, Forschungsbericht</booktitle>
    <pages></pages>
    <authors>
        <author>Andreas Neumann</author>
        <author>Helmut Seidl</author>
    </authors>
</pub>
```

**Full code from edit (with to ElementTree)**

```
#for execute command to work
import sqlite3
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
con = sqlite3.connect("publications.db")
cur = con.cursor()

from xml.dom import minidom
#use this to clean the foreign characters
import re

def anglicise(matchobj): 
    if matchobj.group(0) == '&amp;':
        return matchobj.group(0)
    else:
        return matchobj.group(0)[1]

outputFilename = 'pubsClean.xml'

with open('test.xml') as inXML, open(outputFilename, 'w') as outXML:
    outXML.write('<root>\n')
    for line in inXML.readlines():
        if (line.find("<sub>") or line.find("</sub>")):
            newline = line.replace("<sub>", "")
            newLine = newline.replace("</sub>", "")
        outXML.write(re.sub('&[a-zA-Z]+;',anglicise,newLine))
    outXML.write('\n</root>')


tree = ET.parse('pubsClean.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

xmldoc = minidom.parse('pubsClean.xml')
#loop through <pub> tags to find number of pubs to grab
root2 = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName("root")[0]
pubs = [a.firstChild.data for a in root2.getElementsByTagName("pub")]
num_pubs = len(pubs)
count = 0

while(count < num_pubs):

    temp_pages = 0
    #get data from each <pub> tag

    temp_ID = root.find(".//ID").text
    temp_title = root.find(".//title").text
    temp_year = root.find(".//year").text
    temp_booktitle = root.find(".//booktitle").text
    #handling no value
    if root.find(".//pages").text:  
        temp_pages = root.find(".//pages").text
    else: 
        temp_pages = -1 

    temp_authors = root.find(".//authors")
    temp_author_array = [a.text for a in temp_authors.findall(".//author")]
    num_authors = len(temp_author_array)
    count = count + 1

    #process results into sqlite
    pub_params = (temp_ID, temp_title)
    cur.execute("INSERT OR IGNORE INTO publication (id, ptitle) VALUES (?, ?)", pub_params)
    cur.execute("INSERT OR IGNORE INTO journal (jtitle, pages, year, pub_id, pub_title) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)", (temp_booktitle, temp_pages, temp_year, temp_ID, temp_title))
    x = 0
    while(x < num_authors):
        cur.execute("INSERT OR IGNORE INTO authors (name, pub_id, pub_title) VALUES (?, ?, ?)", (temp_author_array[x],temp_ID, temp_title))
        cur.execute("INSERT OR IGNORE INTO wrote (name, jtitle) VALUES (?, ?)", (temp_author_array[x], temp_booktitle))   
        x = x + 1


con.commit()
con.close()    

print("\nNumber of entries processed: ", count)
```

Comment: It would be easier to help if you showed us complete, copy-pastable code + the XML being processed. In short, provide a [mcve].

Comment: @mzjn okay, sorry, new to the site, I didn't want it to be too long. I'll add it now.

Comment: Sorry to be such a nag, but you should put more effort into making the example MINIMAL and COMPLETE. The sqlite stuff seems irrelevant, for example. And please decide whether you are asking about minidom or ElementTree. The "XML being processed" is not really XML since there is no root element. I do notice that you add the root element in your code, but that seems unrelated to the errors you are getting.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `attributes` method to get a dictionary-like object ([Doc](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/xml.dom.html?highlight=getelementsbytagname#xml.dom.Node.attributes)) and then query the dictionary:

```
if temp_pub.getElementsByTagName("pages").attributes.get('data'):
```

Answer (score 0):

As the error message suggest `getElementsByTagName()` returns neither single node nor `None`, but `NodeList. So you should check the length to see if the returned list contains any item :

```
if len(temp_pub.getElementsByTagName("pages")) > 0:  
    temp_pages = temp_pub.getElementsByTagName("pages")[0].firstChild.data
```

or you can pass the list directly to `if` since empty list is *falsy* :

```
if temp_pub.getElementsByTagName("pages"):  
    temp_pages = temp_pub.getElementsByTagName("pages")[0].firstChild.data
```

---

Side note, despite the title and the tag of this question, your code suggests that you're using `minidom` instead of `ElementTree`. Your code could be simpler using `ElementTree`, for example :

```
# minidom
temp_ID = temp_pub.getElementsByTagName("ID")[0].firstChild.data
# finding single element can be using elementtree's `find()`
temp_ID = temp_pub.find(".//ID").text
....
# minidom
temp_author_array = [a.firstChild.data for a in temp_authors.getElementsByTagName("author")]
# finding multiple elements using elementtree's `find_all()`
temp_author_array = [a.text for a in temp_authors.find_all(".//author")]
```

Comment: `TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'NodeList' and 'int'` from the first, same error as original from second.

When I attempted to print the node, I got a <0x0008HXX> value, is that the start of the list?

Comment: still getting that NoneType error even with the len() edit

Comment: Added adjustments to Etree to my original post, I am still getting an error `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'find_all'`

Comment: You want to get reference to the element, not the inner text, so that you can call `find_all` on that element : `temp_authors = root.find(".//authors")`

Comment: Okay, telling me my `'list' object has no attribute 'findall'`, on the line `temp_author_array = [a.text for a in temp_authors.findall(".//author")]`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142690/discussion-between-har07-and-douglasrcjames).